# JavaScript get image from web path

Tags: javascript, image

My goal is to display a picture from web path. My program automatically gets json formated posts from reddit. Then it takes the path to the image from the response and it looks like this:

```
https://preview.redd.it/8skueonh6fm21.jpg?auto=webp&s=c189f2a13149d5b3a35b4e84370876e6a8801209
```

Question is, how can i get the image from that adress? Like .jpg?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need javascript...

```html
<html>
<img src = "https://preview.redd.it/8skueonh6fm21.jpg?auto=webp&s=c189f2a13149d5b3a35b4e84370876e6a8801209" width="100vw" height= "100vh"/>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addUsers(response) {
  response.data.forEach((user) => {
   $(".user_wrapper").append(
     '<div>' +
       '<span>' + user.first_name + ' </span>' +
       '<img src=' + user.avatar + '>' +
     '</div>'
    ) 
  })
}
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $.get( "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2", 
   function( response ) {
      addUsers(response)
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div class="user_wrapper"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```